# Async server with multiple processes

Tags: python, asynchronous

I want to implement a web server with prefork async architecture.

I use python 3.4 and implement my own event loop. I create socket, make it non blocking and then fork process. After that I init DefaultSelector for event loop. But I receive the same events in different processes. Then in one of processes I get IOBlockingError because the event has already been handled. How should I use DefaultSelector to avoid getting the same events in different processes?

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import os
from selectors import DefaultSelector, EVENT_READ, EVENT_WRITE


def main():
    def readable(soc, mask):
        try:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
        except:
            print('here the problem')
            return

        selector.register(conn, EVENT_READ, readable2)

    def readable2(conn, mask):
        selector.unregister(conn)
        data = conn.recv(100000)
        selector.register(conn, EVENT_WRITE, writable)

    def writable(conn, mask):
        conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        selector.unregister(conn)
        conn.close()

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.setblocking(False)

    sock.bind(('', 8070))
    sock.listen(1000)

    os.fork()
    selector = DefaultSelector()
    selector.register(sock.fileno(), EVENT_READ, readable)
    while True:
        events = selector.select()
        for key, mask in events:
            callb = key.data
            callb(key.fileobj, mask)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Start an event without any connection ! Accept first later put to in another processes.`Accept` is not `selectable` function !

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets 
Usage of non-blocking socket accept function is selectable. Am I wrong?